# Disable comments/posts on event wall through API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall, facebook-events

When using the Graph API to publish an event to a Facebook page is it possible to set the event to "Only admins can post to the event wall" like in the event dialogue available on Facebook.com?

I cannot find any information in the API reference documents to this setting or field (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/)

Thanks in advance!